# Taking quotes out of CSV file using PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Basically I'm trying to remove quotes from CSV file using PL/SQL to have a cleaner format.

I know how to do such in python but need to use PL/SQL. I thought using a replace function could be simple so that it would replace all quotes with nothing.

`''. EX("Head 1", "Head 2, Head 3) -> (Head 1, Head 2, Head 3)`

Still do not know how to create a select statement to grab just quotes to use replace.

Comment: SELECT REPLACE(SELECT * FROM CSV, '"', '') FROM CSV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well, you simply need to [`REPLACE`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/REPLACE.htm#SQLRF00697) the quotes with an empty string; for example:

```
select replace ('("Head 1", "Head 2, Head 3)', '"')
from dual
```

which gives:

```
(Head 1, Head 2, Head 3)
```

Comment: So then if there were to be thousands of lines that could have this issue would I just wrap this in a for loop?

Comment: This works on a single value if you use DUAL or for a table if you have your CSV stored in a table. How is your CSV stored? Do you have a single CLOB, a table with a record for every row, ... ?

Comment: @james_weasel, with SQL there's (usually) no need for a for loop.

Comment: The file comes from a server and gives us header by header so a loop to go through all of the parsed data. Since a Select * would only stop after first one

Comment: Try to post the structure you have, some sample data, .. to help us  to reproduce your situation and test some code. [MCVE] could be useful for this.

Comment: Problem is I do not have sample data as of now. Setting up code for future data. Basically should retrieve one unit at a time. So data is same as before just cannot do a Select * on it. WHILE Input IS NOT NULL
 LOOP
  SELECT REPLACE('(SELECT * FROM Input)', '"')
  FROM Input
 END LOOP;

Comment: What is input? Is it a variable? a table? a structure, ...? Without knowing the structure of your input, it's quite impossible to give a working solution